# chart.js上でインタラクティブに図形を表示したい

Tags: javascript, chart.js

お世話になっております。

chart.js　v2.7.2　を使っています。

その際、任意の位置にfillrect()などで描画をオーバーレイしたいのですが、
インタラクティブに動作させることが出来ません。

見よう見まねで以下のように実装してみましたが、図形は描画されるものの、
変数(posZoomLeft等)を変更しても、関数が再評価されないので、値が更新されません。

```
Chart.defaults.derivedLine = Chart.defaults.line;

var custom = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
    draw: function(ease) {
        Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.call(this, ease);

        ctx.save();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.strokeRect(posZoomLeft, posZoomTop, posZoomWidth, posZoomHeight);
        ctx.restore();
    }
});

Chart.controllers.derivedLine = custom;
```

出来ればchart.jsそのものは弄る事無く実現したいのですが、
何か方法があればアドバイスいただけませんでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。